# How can I flip a zoomable svg vertically in d3.js?

Tags: javascript, svg, d3.js

I'm trying to visualize a geometric dataset as an SVG using d3 whose y axis goes in the inverse direction's of d3 (in my dataset, up is positive whereas in d3 down is positive). As a result, my svg currently is mirrored upside down from the way I would like it to appear.

I want users to be able pan, zoom, and draw on the canvas, and so am trying to flip the image in the most minimal way -- ideally only in one location rather than applying a scale every time data is handled. Is there a way to do so?

```
  const svg = d3.select<SVGSVGElement, unknown>(d3Container.current);
  const g = svg.append("g");

  const zoom = d3.zoom<SVGSVGElement, unknown>().on("zoom", (event) => {
    const { transform } = event;
    g.attr("transform", transform);
  });

  const filledRegions = g.selectAll(".filledRegions");
  filledRegions.data(data).join(
    (enter) =>
      enter
        .append("path")
        .attr("class", "filledRegions")
        .attr("d", (d) => datumToPath(d))
        .attr("fill", (d) => d.fill.color)
  );

  svg.call(zoom);

  const boundingBox = g?.node()?.getBBox();

  if (boundingBox) {
    const { x: x0, y: y0, width: bbWidth, height: bbHeight } = boundingBox;
    const x1 = x0 + bbWidth;
    const y1 = y0 + bbHeight;

    const { clientHeight: frameHeight, clientWidth: frameWidth } =
      d3Container.current;

    svg.call(
      zoom.transform,
      d3.zoomIdentity
        .translate(frameWidth / 2, frameHeight / 2)
        .scale(
          Math.min(
            8,
            0.9 / Math.max((x1 - x0) / frameWidth, (y1 - y0) / frameHeight)
          )
        )
        .translate(-(x0 + x1) / 2, -(y0 + y1) / 2)
    );
```

Comment: *"in my dataset, up is positive whereas in d3 down is positive"*... well, there's no such a thing like *d3 axis* or d3 coordinates. Your problem has nothing to do with D3, that's the SVG specs, where <0,0> is the top left corner. The solution is just using the adequate scale in your line generator.

Comment: You might prefer to draw the whole chart right side up instead of just flipping the zoomed-in part. As Gerardo commented, adapt the scale for this. Simply flipping the scale's domain parameters should do the trick.